Maximal ideal in the ring of formal power series in finitely many variables
Let $k$ be a field, $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots\}$ be the set of prime numbers in order. Consider the rings $P=k[[x_1,\ldots,x_m]]$ of formal power series in $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ variables and $R=k[[x_1,x_2,\ldots]]$ of formal power series in countably many variables. I've proven that $P$ is a local ring so it has a unique maximal ideal. Is this maximal ideal $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$? Furthermore, I would like to find a proof in a purely arithmetic context, using arithmetic functions as follows:
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of arithmetic functions and consider the isomorphism of rings $\phi: \mathcal{A} \longrightarrow R$ defined as $\phi(f) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(n) x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_j^{\alpha_j}$ where $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_j^{\alpha_j}$ is the prime factorization of $n$. Then $\phi(f*g)=\phi(f)\phi(g)$, where $*$ is the Dirichlet convolution. Then $P$ can be identified with the subring $\mathcal{A}_m=\{f \in \mathcal{A} \mid f(n) = 0 \text{ if } n \text{ is not of the form } n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}, \alpha_i \ge 0\}$ and the variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ can be identified with the functions (in $\mathcal{A}_m$) defined as $g_i(p_i)=1$ and $g_i(n) = 0$ otherwise. So I need to show that if $N$ is an ideal such that $(g_1,\ldots,g_m)=M_m \subset N \subset \mathcal{A}_m$ then $N=M_m$ or $N=\mathcal{A}_m$. Some observations:

If $I$, the identity arithmetic function, is in $N$ then $N=\mathcal{A}_m$ and there is nothing to prove.
If $N \ne \mathcal{A}_m$ then $I \not\in N$, then $f(1)=0$ for all $f \in N$, since $f(1) \ne 0$ implies that $f^{-1}$ exists and it is in $M$ so $I \in N$. I'd then like to prove that every $f \in N$ can be written as $f=f_1*g_1 + \cdots + f_m*g_m$, $f_i \in \mathcal{A}_m$.
Suppose that is the case and let $n>2$, $n=p_{i_1}^{\alpha_{i_1}}\cdots p_{i_r}^{\alpha_{i_r}}$, where $i_j \le m, \alpha_{i_j} \ge 1$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
(f_1*g_1)(p_{i_1}^{\alpha_{i_1}}\cdots p_{i_r}^{\alpha_{i_r}})+\cdots+(f_m*g_m)(p_{i_1}^{\alpha_{i_1}}\cdots p_{i_r}^{\alpha_{i_r}}) &= f_{i_1}(p_{i_1}^{\alpha_{i_1}-1}\cdots p_{i_r}^{\alpha_{i_r}})g_{i_1}(p_{i_1})+\cdots+f_{i_r}(p_{i_1}^{\alpha_{i_1}}\cdots p_{i_r}^{\alpha_{i_r}-1})g_{i_r}(p_{i_r}) \\
&= f_{i_1}(p_{i_1}^{\alpha_{i_1}-1}\cdots p_{i_r}^{\alpha_{i_r}})+\cdots+f_{i_r}(p_{i_1}^{\alpha_{i_1}}\cdots p_{i_r}^{\alpha_{i_r}-1})
\end{align}
$$
I can't see how this last expression can be equal to $f(n)$, nor how to define each $f_i$.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Is there a particular reason why you don't want to just consider the quotient of $P$ by $(x_1, \dots, x_m)$?

No, but it would be nice to consider $\mathcal{A}_m$ and $(g_1,\ldots,g_m)$ instead. If not, honestly any clue would help me, and I could then translate it into the language of arithmetic functions.

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $\mathcal A_R(N)= \{f\colon N\to R\}$ is the ring of $R$-valued functions on an abelian monoid  (= semigroup with identity) $N$, then $\mathcal A$ is a ring under the point-wise operations of addition and multiplication. However, because $N$ is a monoid, it is also a ring under pointwise addition and convolution: the monoid operation on $N$ gives a map $p\colon  N \times N \to N$, where $(m,n)\mapsto m+n$.
Assumption: If $m \in N$ then $p^{-1}(m)=\{(r,s)\in N\times N: r+s=m\}$ is finite.
Whenever the assumption holds, we can define $p_*\colon \mathcal A_R(N)\times \mathcal A_R(N) \to \mathcal A_R(N)$ by
$$
p_*(f,g)(n)= (f*g)(n) = \sum_{(k,l)\in p^{-1}(n)} f(k)g(l)
$$
so that $(\mathcal A_R(N),+,*)$ is a ring where $+$ is pointwise addition and $f*g:=p_*(f,g)$, with multiplicative identity given by the indicator function $e$ of the identity in $N$, that is $e(n)=0$ unless $n=0$ and $e(0)=1$.
The monoid $(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0},+,0)$ satisfies the assumption, hence $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0})$ is a ring under convolution. If we let $t \in \mathcal A$ be the function given by $t(n)=0$ unless $n=1$, and $t(1)=1$, then $t^k(n)=0$ unless $n=k$ where $t^k(k)=1$ and we have, for any $f \in \mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0})$ we have
$$
f = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(n)t^n
$$
where this sum makes sense in $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0})$ because for any $k \in \mathbb Z$ only finitely many (in fact only one) of the terms on the right-hand side is non-zero. Thus $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}) = R[\![t]\!]$ is the ring of formal power series in $t$ with coefficients in $R$.
Now take the multiplicative monoid $\mathbb N = (\mathbb Z_{>0},\times,1)$, then $\mathbb N \cong P=\prod'_{\mathbb N} \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$, the "restricted product" of countably many copies of $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ via prime factorization: if $p_1<p_2<\ldots $ denote the prime numbers, then $n \in \mathbb N$ can be written uniquely as $p_{i_1}^{k_{i_1}}\ldots p_{i_m}^{k_{i_m}}$ for $i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_m$ and $k_{i_r} \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$. The map $\mathbb N \to P$ is then given by $n \mapsto (l_i)$ where if $i=i_r$ for some $r \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ then $l_i = k_{i_r}$ and $l_i=0$ otherwise. Here the "restricted product" is the submonoid of the product consisting of the elements which have only finitely many non-zero terms, and so is the union of $\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0} :=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ of the finite products ($n \geq 1$).
It follows that $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb N) \cong \mathcal A_R(P)$. Let $t_i \in \mathcal A_R(P)$ be the function which takes the value $0$ on $(l_j)$ unless $l_j=0$ for all $j \neq i$ and $l_i=1$. Then if $f \in \mathcal A_R(P)$ we have $f =  \sum_{(l_i)\in P} f((l_i))\prod_{i=1}^\infty t_i^{l_i}$. Here the infinite product makes sense because only finitely many of the $l_i$ are nonzero, and again the infinite sum which has only finitely many terms not equal to zero when evaluated on any element of $P$. Thus $\mathcal A_R(P)$ is equal to $R[\![x_i: i \in \mathbb N]\!]$, the ring of formal power series in countably many variables.
If we write $\underline{t}^{(l_i)}:=\prod_{i=1}^\infty t_i^{l_i}$ then  $\mathcal A_R(P)$ contains the ring $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n)$ as the subring
$$
\mathcal A_{R,n}(P):=\{f \in \mathcal A_R(P): f= \sum f((l_i)\underline{t}^{(l_i)}: f((l_i))\neq 0 \implies \forall i>N, l_i=0\}
$$
Now the inclusion map $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n \to P$ (given by sending an $n$-tuple $\mathbf l = (l_1,\ldots,l_n)$ to the sequence which has its first $n$ terms equal to those of $\mathbf l$ and all other terms equal to $0$ induces a restriction map $r_n \colon \mathcal A_{R}(P) \to \mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n)$ which is easily seen to be a homomorphism of rings. Since this map restricts to an isomorphism from $\mathcal A_{R,n}(P)$ to $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0})$, it follows that if $f \in \mathcal A_{R,n}(P)$ is a unit in $\mathcal A_R(P)$, then it is a unit in $\mathcal A_{R,n}(P)$: if $f \in \mathcal A_{R,n}(P)$ has $f*g=e$ then $r_n(f)r_n(g) = r_n(e) = e_n$ where $e_n$ is the indicator function of $0^n \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n$, the identity element in $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z^n)$. Thus if $s_n \colon \mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n) \to \mathcal A_R(P)$ is the inverse of the restriction of $r_n$ to $\mathcal A_{R,n}(P)$, then $f*s_n(r_n(g)) = e$, hence as multiplicative inverses in a ring are unique (when they exist), $g =s_nr_n(g)\in \mathcal A_{R,n}(P)$. It follows that the units in $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z^n)$ can be identified with $\mathcal A_{R,n}(P)\cap \mathcal A_R(P)^\times$.
Now consider $\mathcal A_R(P)^\times\cong \mathcal A_R(\mathbb N)$. If $f \in \mathcal A_R(\mathbb N)$ and $f(1)\in R$ is a unit, we claim $f$ is a unit in $\mathcal A_R(\mathcal P)$. Suppose that $f*g= e$ where $e(n)=0$ unless $n=1$, where $e(1)=1$ (this is the multiplicative identity of $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb N)$. Now $f*g(n) = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)$, hence when $n=1$ if $f*g=e$ then $g(1)=f(1)^{-1}$, while if $n >1$ then
$$
0=f*g(n)= f(1)g(n)+\sum_{d\mid n, d>1} f(d)g(n/d) \implies g(n) = -f(1)^{-1}\sum_{d\mid n, d>1} f(d)g(n/d),
$$
and hence we see that $g\in \mathcal A_R(\mathbb N)$ is uniquely determined recursively from $g(1)=f(1)^{-1}$. Thus the units $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb N)^\times$ in $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb N)$ are precisely  $\{f \in \mathcal A_R(\mathbb N): f(1)\in R^\times\}$. If we now assume that $R=\mathsf k$ is a field, the units are $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb N)^\times = \{f \in \mathcal A_R(\mathbb N): f(1)\neq 0\}$
The isomorphism $\mathcal A_{\mathsf k}(\mathbb N)\cong \mathcal A_{\mathsf k}(P)$ thus shows that $\mathcal A_{\mathsf k}(P)^\times = \{f \in \mathcal A_{\mathsf k}(P): f(0)\neq 0\}$, and hence as $s_n(\mathcal A_{\mathsf k}(\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0})^\times) = \mathcal  A_{\mathsf k,n}(P)\cap \mathcal A_{\mathsf k}(P)^\times$ we see that
$$
\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n)^\times = \{f \in \mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n): f(0^n)\neq 0\}.
$$
But now it follows that if $f\in \mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0})$ is not a unit, then $f \in M:=\sum_{i=1}^n t_i\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}^n)$, the kernel of the map given by $f \mapsto f(0^n)$. But then as $\mathsf k$ is a field, it follows that $M$ is a maximal ideal, and since it contains all non-units in $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0})$, it contains every proper ideal in $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0})$. Thus $\mathcal A_R(\mathbb Z^n_{\geq 0})$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $M$.
